# Укажите, пожалуйста, ошибки (из газет и устной речи)

Tags: грамотная-речь

*«Омхачивание» всех советских театров происходило  как коллективизация и индустриализация.*

*Недавно закончилась в Питере конференция, где обсуждались проблемы реформации русского языка на стыке тысячелетий.*

*Коллеги-журналисты в связи с этим понаписали и понаобещали по телевизору много всяких ужасных вещей, вплоть до тотального переучивания правил проважания.*

Помогите объяснить их и исправить,

спасибо.

Comment: А что такое "проважание"? Никогда не встречал такого слова.

Comment: Я тоже, поэтому и не могу справиться с этим заданием..

Comment: Это опечатка, на одном из сайтов-"правописания".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.«Омхачивание» всех советских театров происходило как коллективизация и индустриализация. Омхачивание- **неуместное использование окказионализма** (авторского неологизма).

Речь о том, что в театральном процессе страны в 1937 г. начинается кампания «равнение на МХАТ» – процесс силового административно-командного «омхачивания» (по выражению современников) советских театров всех жанров как часть огосударствления структур литературы и культуры.

2.Недавно закончилась в Питере конференция, где обсуждались проблемы реформации русского языка на стыке тысячелетий.

Неверный выбор паронима: нужно было употребить **реформирование русского языка.**

3.Коллеги-журналисты в связи с этим понаписали и понаобещали по телевизору много всяких ужасных вещей, вплоть до тотального переучивания правил правописания (**проважания - опечатка, на одном из сайтов в заданиях нашла верный вариант**).

Стилистические ошибки: употребление **просторечий** "понаписали" и "понаобещали", "ужасных вещей" и **разговорной формы** "по телевизору" вместо "по телевидению" **в тексте** **публицистического стиля**.